# Angular 4 - file not found

Tags: angular, file, csv, http-status-code-404

I am using Angular 4 and I am trying to load .csv data, in example in this way: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/read-csv-data-using-angular-2.html but I can't load sample.csv file. I have tried to add this file to src/app or src or root / but I have the same problem all the time:

```
GET XHR http://localhost:4200/sample.csv [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 6 ms]
404 - Not Found
```

I am using ng serve to run it on localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular you can access static file from assets folder

copy sample.csv file into app/assets folder.

Access like this

```
this.http.get("./sample.csv")
            .map((res: any) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Angular CLI.  By default static content will only be delivered from the assets folder.  You can change this by modifying the .angular-cli.json configuration file in the root of your application.  Look for the assets array and add your custom files or folders here:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "my-csv-data.csv"
      ],
```